# Changing opacity for GeoJSON feature using d3 and Leaflet

Tags: d3.js, leaflet, geojson

I'm new to `d3.js` and trying to use it in my LeafletMap. I have some GeoJSON feature that contains LineString geometry with a list of `100 lon/lat coordinates`, something like:

```
{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[120.490741,-11.045729],[120.4889,-11.04797],..]}.
```

I need the last 2/3 part of this line to "`fade away"` slowly, using the opacity. For example, the opacity of the line from it's left end is 0.8 for 2/3 of the length, then it becomes 0.7 for the next small section, then 0.6, 0.5 and so on, until it reaches 0 at the right end of the line.

How can it be done using d3.js with Leaflet?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it if you convert your `LineString`'s into `MultiLineString`'s.

Leaflet converts `LineString` into `L.Polyline` and `MultiLineString` into `L.MultiPolyline`

In `L.MultiPolyline` every line segment is represented by another layer (another geometry (`<g><path></path></g>`) in SVG terms). You can loop through those layers and set different style to them.

**Sample code**

```
var latngs = ... // array of arrays of coordinates (see below for sample definition)

var p = L.multiPolyline(latlngs);

p.addTo(map);

p.getLayers().forEach(function(layer, index){
    var opacity = 1 - index / 10; // decreasing the opacity with 0.1 for each line segment
    layer.setStyle({opacity: opacity})
}
```

**Result**

[image: Fading line]

```
var latngs = [
    [
        [6329.8125, -2014.4750909626719],
        [6362.859375, -2013.6042942934673]
    ],
    [
        [6362.859375, -2013.6042942934673],
        [6395.90625, -2018.3907793950361]
    ],
    [
        [6395.90625, -2018.3907793950361],
        [6411.375, -2014.0346123008687]
    ],
    [
        [6411.375, -2014.0346123008687],
        [6452.859375, -2012.977408428527]
    ],
    [
        [6452.859375, -2012.977408428527],
        [6472.546875, -2023.4066591698797]
    ],
    [
        [6472.546875, -2023.4066591698797],
        [6509.8125, -2017.3434450152427]
    ],
    [
        [6509.8125, -2017.3434450152427],
        [6589.265625, -2018.1244586532705]
    ],
    [
        [6589.265625, -2018.1244586532705],
        [6610.359375, -2031.0223863293038]
    ],
    [
        [6610.359375, -2031.0223863293038],
        [6627.234375, -2076.2043224171703]
    ],
    [
        [6627.234375, -2076.2043224171703],
        [6639.1875, -2111.165173368664]
    ],
    [
        [6639.1875, -2111.165173368664],
        [6634.96875, -2138.9089020477704]
    ],
    [
        [6634.96875, -2138.9089020477704],
        [6631.453125, -2151.366836892263]
    ],
    [
        [6631.453125, -2151.366836892263],
        [6628.640625, -2156.8446726342527]
    ],
    [
        [6628.640625, -2156.8446726342527],
        [6655.359375, -2159.428423641068]
    ],
    [
        [6655.359375, -2159.428423641068],
        [6672.9375, -2159.8248203461394]
    ],
    [
        [6672.9375, -2159.8248203461394],
        [6698.953125, -2159.428423641068]
    ],
    [
        [6698.953125, -2159.428423641068],
        [6715.828125, -2159.226699693061]
    ]
]
```

**XML representation of the resulting SVG**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg class="leaflet-zoom-animated" width="635" height="500" viewBox="177 127 635 500" style="transform: translate3d(177px, 127px, 0px);">
    <g> <path stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" stroke="#0033ff" stroke-opacity="0.9" stroke-width="5" fill="none" class="leaflet-clickable" d="M381 305L409 304"/> </g>

    <g> <path stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" stroke="#0033ff" stroke-opacity="0.8" stroke-width="5" fill="none" class="leaflet-clickable" d="M409 304L436 308"/> </g>

    <g> <path stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" stroke="#0033ff" stroke-opacity="0.7" stroke-width="5" fill="none" class="leaflet-clickable" d="M436 308L449 304"/> </g>

    <g> <path stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" stroke="#0033ff" stroke-opacity="0.6" stroke-width="5" fill="none" class="leaflet-clickable" d="M449 304L484 303"/> </g>
    ....
    ....
    ....
</svg>
```

**P.S.:**

When using `L.Polyline` the whole line is only single SVG geometry (`<g><path></path><g>`) and I don't think it's possible to achieve what you want.